# MySQL Query with count(*) and group by

Tags: mysql

I have a table (wccrm_anprobe) with a model, a branch, a date and a state. I need to have a list ordered by month, branch and then a count(*) by model where state = 1

I have attached an Image to visualise how it should looks like.

Thank you for any help[image: ![It should look like this]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb4Cd.png)

I tried with that SQL Statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), model, branch, date
FROM wccrm_anprobe
GROUP BY date , branch
```

But the output is just the days and the number of models, and not all date merged into months...

Best Regards,

Stefan

Comment: and what SQL have you tried thus far?

Comment: Question examples using images are bad i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Hint:  `SELECT <some_columns>, COUNT(*) ... WHERE state = 1 GROUP BY <some_columns>`.. Keep <some_columns> the same..

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions. I have solved it that way:

```
SELECT count(*) as Anzahl, MONTHNAME( date ) AS Monat, YEAR( date ) AS Jahr, branch,     
ordered as Verkauf FROM wccrm_anprobe where status = 1 GROUP BY 
MONTHNAME(date),YEAR(date), branch, ordered ORDER BY date,branch ASC
```

Best Regards,

Stefan